# Laravel 5 + SQL Server and encoding errors

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, encoding, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5 and SQL Server to fetch some data.

Whenever the data has some special characters *(éêè etc.)* Laravel doesn't show the column value, as if it was just nothing. (not null either).

I tried some SQL commands via tinker, and got the same results. My titles doesn't show up whenever they have special characters.

The database is encoded with this collation : ***Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS*** 
And my database.php looks like this :

```
<?php
      return [
      'connections' => [
                'mysql' => [/*my mysql connection*/],
                'dbmssql' => [
                            'driver'    => 'sqlsrv',
                            'host'      => 'host',
                            'database'  => '',
                            'username'  => 'username',
                            'password'  => 'password',
                            'prefix'    => '',
                            'collation' =>  'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS',
                            'charset'   =>  'latin1'
                        ],
                ]
      ];
```

We have tried almost everything. Changing the collation/charset, adding a "Cast()" to our SQL commands etc. None of them works.
We can't even get the data with bad encodings. It just returns nothing.

Here is the tinker result :

- The first result has been added through Laravel, so the encoding works Laravel-side, but on the SQL Server its badly encoded
- Second result has no special char. and show up normally on both side
- Third result has special char. on SQL Server, Laravel doesn't show it at all.

> ```
>       id: "1",
>       titre: "ûéÉàÀêÊïÏçÇ",
>       etat: "1",
>       created_at: "May 29 2015 08:04:43:000PM",
>       updated_at: "Jun  1 2015 03:24:44:000PM"
>   },
>   <stdClass #000000005a3cad49000000000aae376c> {
>       id: "2",
>       titre: "Administration",
>       etat: "1",
>       created_at: "Jun  1 2015 08:55:00:000AM",
>       updated_at: "Jun  1 2015 08:55:00:000AM"
>   },
>   <stdClass #000000005a3cad4c000000000aae376c> {
>       id: "3",
>       titre: ,
>       etat: "1",
>       created_at: "Jun  1 2015 08:55:00:000AM",
>       updated_at: "Jun  1 2015 08:55:00:000AM"
>   },
> ```

Has anyone run into something similar?

**UPDATE**

I finally made it work using the mutators!  Here is my Model function code if anyone else runs into this situation.

```
public function getTitreAttribute($title){
    return utf8_encode($title);
}

public function setTitreAttribute($titre){
    $this->attributes['titre'] =  utf8_decode($titre);
}
```

Comment: I have a similar problem. Can you help me? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46718364/laravel-collection-accentuation-error?noredirect=1#comment80385575_46718364