# Laravel collection accentuation error

Tags: php, sql-server, json, laravel

I have a big problem with my program (WebAPI) made in Laravel.

First, this is software's configuration:

- Laravel Framework 5.4.30
- SQL Server 2012

---

I was trying to return a Json of the table "students", but this Json returned error when the field "name" contain accentuations, example 'José'. When it doesn't contain accentuations, the Json returned with all rows,  example 'Maria'

I saw the collection returned when I realized a letter before the value of the name field.

```html
class StudentsController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request){

        $class = $request['class'];

        $return = DB::table('students')
        ->where("class", $class)
        ->get();
        
        dd($return);
        
        return json_encode($return);
        
    }

}
```

This result doesn't have accentuations:

```html
Collection {#289
  #items: array:1 [
    0 => {#284
      +"id": "2"
      +"name": "Maria"
      +"class": "B"
    }
  ]
}
```

Convert to Json: `return json_encode($return);` , return:

```
[{"id":"2","name":"Maria","class":"B"}]
```

But.. when the result have a accentuations:

```html
Collection {#289
  #items: array:1 [
    0 => {#284
      +"id": "1"
      +"name": b"José"
      +"class": "A"
    }
  ]
}
```

Repair the letter **"b"** before the value.

Convert to Json(`return json_encode($return);`) , return:
[Json whith problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GolB.png)

This is the configuration of connection on the file "/config/database.php"

```html
'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD'),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
        ]
```

Help me!!!

Comment: try running the string through the iconv function and see if that helps https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way achieve this rather than returning a `json_encode` try to return a collection.

```
class StudentsController extends Controller
{
   public function index(Request $request){

    $class = $request['class'];

    $return = DB::table('students')
    ->where("class", $class)
    ->get();


    return $return;

   }
}
```

It will return the result as expected.

Comment: Hello! The postman returned :The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "boolean" given.